# Finding roots of a nonlinear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations

I plotted the functions $y=2x$ and $y=\ln(1+x)$ and they have two intersecting points. So the equation $2x=\ln(1+x)$ is supposed to have two roots. One of them is obviously $x=0$. How can I get the other one?

Comment: Did you use a plotting program or did you plot it by hand? If the former, you can zoom in by reading the approximate value of the zero and limiting the range of the graph appropriately. E.g. using `gnuplot`, I can see that it's at about -0.8, so limiting to the range of $x$ to $[-0.81, -0.79]$, I get a pretty good approximation to a straight line, and can do simple linear interpolation: I get $-0.8 + 2/3\times 0.005 \approx -0.7967$ by eyeballing the intersections with the grid lines. Rough, but handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no analytic solution to this equation in terms of elementary functions. Yet, good approximations can still be obtained.

For example, let the root be $r=-1+a$ and expand the function

$$f(x) = e^{2x} - x -1$$

around $x=-1$ to get,

$$f(r) = 0 \approx f(-1) +f'(-1)a + \frac 12 f''(-1) a^2\tag{1}$$

Evaluate,

$$f(-1) = e^{-2}, \>\>\> f'(-1) = 2e^{-2}-1, \>\>\> f''(-1) = 4e^{-2}$$

Plug above values into (1) to obtain the approximate root,

$$r \approx -1 + \frac 14\left( e^2 -2 - \sqrt{e^4-4e^2-4}\right) = -0.799$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x = -t/2-1$, the equation says $\ln(-t/2) = -t - 2$. Exponentiating,
$-t/2 = \exp(-t-2)$, i.e. $t \exp(t) = -2 \exp(-2)$.  Thus $t$ is one of the branches of
$W(-2 \exp(-2))$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  Since $-1/e < -2 \exp(-2) < 0$, there are two real branches, the principal branch and the $-1$ branch.  In this case the $-1$ branch is $-2$, leading to $x=0$,  the principal branch is approximately $-0.4063757400$, leading to $x = -t/2-1 \approx -0.7968121301$.